# Looping div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am just curious how to loop a `div` from my return `json` result.

This is my desired result:

```
<div id="imgdiv">
  --wanna loop this div and all the inner div and everything as well 
  <div id="rbox" style="display:none">
    Doa ini telah dihantar sebanyak <span class="counter"></span> kali.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span class="buttonshare"><a href="">Klik untuk pilih doa</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my current jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({type :'GET',
        url : 'getallimg.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
            $("#loader").hide(500);
            $("<div class='imgdiv'><img src='imagedoa/"+item.imgname+".jpg' width='450' height='150' /></div></br>")
            .appendTo("#doaimgbox");
           });-->stuck up here
```

Here is the desire code I'm looking it

```
<div id="doaimgbox"><!-- parent div -->

       <!-- looping portion -->
      <!-- I wanna loop this div based on length json return result let's say 3 -->

        <div class="imgdiv">

            <img src="imagedoa/d0.jpg" width="400" height="150" />
            <div id="rbox">
                Was sent <span class="counter"></span> times.
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <span class="buttonshare"><a href="">Click to select</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- looping portion -->
</div><!-- end parent div -->
```

Really need help with it.

Comment: What does it do? What does it not do? What have you tried?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: please add to your question the json results

Comment: Can you be more specific? What effect are you trying to achieve? I assume you want your html to look like the upper code, but there is no <img> tag in it. I can help if you would clarify it.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness reply guys and thanks for ur times..click link below to see my image.. so u guys got the big picture of what I'm after..

http://www.socialblit.com/doatowall/demo/viewdesire.jpg

Answer (score 1):

U can add create a template let say name is myTmpl

```
var myTmpl="<div id="imgdiv">--wanna loop this div and all the inner div and everything as well 
            <div id="rbox" style="display:none">
                Doa ini telah dihantar sebanyak <span class="counter"></span> kali.
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <span class="buttonshare"><a href="">Klik untuk pilih doa</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>"
```

and u can use it in your div let's say u want to append this for each data that returned
from your ajax call

```
$.each(data,function(){
    $(myTmpl).appendTo('body');
})
```

Comment: If i try to make a template so how's I gonna view my result return from json...I mean the data itself..